# How to remove text in middle of a field-Mysql query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one mysql table with two fields.`id` and `recipients`. recipients field contains emails as comma separated values`(eg:abc@gmail.com,def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com)`. The table contains 30000 rows. I want to remove one particular email id from all the rows if it exists.

There may be three cases may happen
1)**abc@gmail.com**,def@gmail.com,ghi@gmail.com
2)def@gmail.com,**abc@gmail.com**,fgh2gmail.com
3)def@gmail.com,abc@gmail.com,**abc@gmail.com**

Requirement is, I want to remove **abc@gmail.com** from all the rows.
I know how to append one email

> UPDATE report_ SET recipients = CONCAT('abc@gmail.com.com,', recipients);

When removing email id's ,comma also should be removed. How can I do this using Mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this you can take care of 2 cases: 
'abc@gmail.com.com,'  and  ',abc@gmail.com.com'

**So if databases name is MyDb and if you need to run update, consider:**

```
UPDATE MyDb
SET recepients = REPLACE(REPLACE(recepients, ',abc@gmail.com', ''), 'abc@gmail.com,', '')
```

Comment: is it handle all three cases i mentioned?? Is it handle comma issue also??

Comment: yes, there are only 2 cases really: when comma is before the email or when its after. For case #2 (when comma is before AND after) - you can remove the email with any one of these commas. You need to keep the second comma.

Comment: the way my update works:  in each row it tries to find  'abc@gmail.com.com,' and to replace it to '' (nothing).  Then it tries to find ',abc@gmail.com.com' and to replace it to ''. One or another will for for each row.

Comment: let me know if you have questions - I will explain.